# first activity view does not appear

Tags: java, android

I am new to android. I have two activities Splash and MainActivity. When I launch my application the Splash activity starts(as its supposed to be), it plays the sound but the background image does not appear and some seconds later my MainActivity starts. Thanks in advance!

code for MainActivity class

```
Package com.example.button;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    int counter;
    Button add;
    Button sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter=0;
    add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
public void add(View view)
{
    counter=counter+1;
    display.setText("your total is"+counter);
}

public void sub(View view)
{
     counter--;
     display.setText("your total is"+counter);
}

}
```

code for Splash class

```
package com.example.button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{
MediaPlayer ourSong;
Thread timer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);
     ourSong=MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this,R.raw.addicted);
    ourSong.start();
             timer=new Thread();
            timer.start();                      
            run();
            //{
                        //};


    }

    public void run()
    {

        try {


            timer.sleep(5000);

        }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

        }finally {
Intent openStartingPoint=new Intent("com.example.button.MAINACTIVITY");
            startActivity(openStartingPoint);
        }
        }               




    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
ourSong.release();
    }





}
```

code for splash.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/feather">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post layout - splash.xml

Comment: I have posted the code of splash.xml above.Please have a look at it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not correctly used Thread. change these three lines of your code

```
    timer=new Thread();
    timer.start();                      
    run();
```

to

```
    timer=new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                Intent openStartingPoint=new Intent("com.example.button.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        }               
    });
    timer.start();
```

and remove run method from your activity.
by this way you let the splash activity to appear for 5 seconds on screen.

Answer (score 0):

use this code as your splash activity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {
    int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 1000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_form);

        InitilizeUi();
    }

    private void InitilizeUi() {
        // play your sound
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
                SplashActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                SplashActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your splash.xml take a **imageview** and put your image file there.

e.g `android:src="file.gif"`

hope this helps you`